# Compile java multiple classes inside multiple packages

Tags: java, cmd

I have 3 classes inside 3 different packages and I would like to compile them from dir c
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFmGG.png)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLWnK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhJ52.png)

```
package packagea;
public class ClassA{
public String value = "Hello ";
}
```

```
package packageb;
public class ClassB{
public String value = "World";
}
```

```
package packagec;
import packagea.ClassA;
import packageb.ClassB;
public class Runner{
    
public static void main(String[] arg){
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    
    System.out.println(a.value + b.value);
}
}
```

I want to use cmd to compile them from c dir.
I tried cmd command

`javac -classpath cert/chapter1/code packagea/*.java packageb/*.java packagec/*.java`

I m getting error error:
Invalid filename: packagea/*.java

What I m doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Just FYI, almost no one calls javac directly. I've worked with Java for a decade and I might struggle with this. Use Maven.

Comment: I m learning this because OCP certification and this is one of topics which are required to known. Usually I use IDE so this is also new topic for me and I m struggling with some cases like this :-)

Comment: If your packages are in `c:/cert/chapter1/code` and you are invoking `javac` in the root directory, you need to specify `--sourcepath cert/chapter1/code`, as in `javac -d "cert/chapter1/compiled" -sourcepath "cert/chapter1/code" cert/chapter1/code/**/*.java`.  I added the `-d` output directory option, which segregates the source from the compiled files.

Comment: True, no professional does it ..for decades, but students/beginners/auto didacts could and should! Please read the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) and work on the (os specific!) syntax (wild cards, separators, classpath vs sourcepath...). Your actual error message points to an "invalid filename `packagea/*.java`" (assuming current dir is (Windows) "C:", it sounds very reasonable!;)